# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, .net

Estou com problema ao carregar os dados do *controller* no Angular. Não estou entendendo, segui passo a passo a explicação e o meu deu esse erro.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('clienteController', ['$scope', '$http', clienteController]);

function clienteController($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:26633/api/ClientesWebApi/GetCliente")
    .success(function (data) { $scope.listaclientes = data; })
    .error(function () { $scope.erro = "Não foi possivel carregar a listagem de clientes."; });
}
```

O link que estou passando via Web Api esta trazendo os dados corretamento via Json, mas ao executar a aplicação já mostra o erro na descrição.

O que está ocorrendo? Alguem poderia me explicar?

Answer (score 0):

Este erro não tem a ver com MVC, veja o detalhe do erro e vai ver qual módulo não está sendo injetado no angular.

Tenta mudar seu código pra algo como:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("clienteController", ["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:26633/api/ClientesWebApi/GetCliente")
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.listaclientes = data;
        })
        .error(function () {
            $scope.erro = "Não foi possivel carregar a listagem de clientes.";
        });
}]);
```